# Using R, for each year, I need to sum the sales in different years between same two dates

Tags: r, dplyr

For two different years, for each year, I need to sum all the sales that occurred from January 3 through March 3. I would prefer a dplyr solution.

All the possible solutions I looked at in stackoverflow used SQL, not R. If someone knows of a solution I missed, please let me know.

In R, I know how to work with groups and to use a variety of dplyr functions, but I need help doing what this post is about.

I would like the **output** to look like this:

```
Year   Total Sales
2020   138 
2021   196
```

**Input**

```
df <- data.frame(date=c(20200102, 20200107, 20200210, 20200215, 20200216, 20200302, 20200305, 20210101, 20210104, 20210209, 20210211, 20210215, 20210317, 20210322),
                  sales=c(9,14,27,30,33,34,36,44,45,47,51,53,56,58))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  Convert the 'date' to `Date` class (with `ymd` from `lubridate`), get the  `month` and `day` from the 'date', create a new date with `ISOdate` with `year` standardized to a single year (here we chose 2021 - it can be any year though), then we `filter` the 'newdate' using `between` and specify the `left` and `right` arguments as the custom date range, then do a group by 'year' and get the `sum` of 'sales' in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date), year = year(date),
   month = month(date), day = day(date), 
   newdate = as.Date(ISOdate(2021, month, day))) %>% 
  filter(between(newdate, as.Date("2021-01-03"), 
        as.Date("2021-03-03"))) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(sales = sum(sales))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   year sales
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2020   138
#2  2021   196
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`.  Create the 'newdate' by `sub`sitution i.e. remove the first 4 characters (`.{4}`) from the start (`^`) of the 'date', replace with '2021', convert to `Date` class, do a `subset` with relational operators.  Then use the filtered dataset in `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'sales' by the `year` part i.e. first 4 characters

```
subdf <- subset(transform(df, newdate = as.Date(sub("^.{4}", "2021", 
         date), '%Y%m%d')),
     newdate >= as.Date('2021-01-03') & newdate <= as.Date('2021-03-03'))
aggregate(sales ~ cbind(Year = substr(date, 1, 4)), subdf, FUN = sum)
#  Year sales
#1 2020   138
#2 2021   196
```

Answer (score 5):

One row less than my master akrun's solution :)

1. With `ymd` function of `lubridate` package transform character type to date.
2. With `DayMonth` function consider only month and day for the desired interval by month and day
3. group by `year`
4. filter the interval
5. summarise

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
    mutate(DayMonth = format(as.Date(date), "%m-%d")) %>% 
    group_by(Year=year(date)) %>% 
    filter(DayMonth>"01-03" & DayMonth<"03-03") %>% 
    summarise(Total_Sales = sum(sales))
```

Output:

```
   Year Total_Sales
  <int>       <dbl>
1  2020         138
2  2021         196
```

Comment: Upvoted dear @TarJae, you may further shorten it by at least one more line, `df %>%   group_by(Year = year(ymd(date))) %>%   mutate(DayMonth = format(ymd(date), "%m-%d")) %>%  filter(DayMonth > "01-03" & DayMonth < "03-03") %>% summarise(Total_Sales = sum(sales))`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following solution for your purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(year = year(date)) %>%
  filter(date %within% interval(ymd(paste(first(year), "01-03", sep = "-")), 
                                ymd(paste(first(year), "03-03", sep = "-")))) %>%
  summarise(sale = sum(sales))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   year  sale
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2020   138
2  2021   196
```

Comment: Very nice! Even one row less :)

Comment: That's very kind of you my friend. I know it's rather unusual, thought try to take this form to differ from what you guys already posted.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution using only integer/modulo division, `%%` & `%/%`, i.e. without using any date type library (lubridate, etc.)

- Since your date variable follow most logical (and most suited for aplhabetical sorting of dates) format, the job here is to check condition/grouping over first four digits, filtering over last four digits and summarise.  So
- `group_by` on `Year` which is obtained by integer division i.e. `%/%` date by `10000` which will give you first four digits always (in case of YYYYMMDD format)
- No need to create this column first and then group_by
- Thereafter filter in the rows using modulo division `%%` of `date` by `10000` obtaining last four digits and check your condition
- summarise lastly
- In case your date column is of character type wrap it with `as.numeric` in all the steps

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Year = date %/% 10000) %>%
  filter(date %% 10000 > 103, date %% 10000 < 303) %>%
  summarise(Total_sales = sum(sales))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>    Year Total_sales
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1  2020         138
#> 2  2021         196
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

equivalent baseR syntax

```
aggregate(sales ~ cbind(Year = date %/% 10000), 
          subset(df, date %% 10000 > 103 & date %% 10000 < 303), 
          FUN = sum)
  Year sales
1 2020   138
2 2021   196
```